# How do categories and subcategories for WooCommerce are saved in DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with categories and subcategories in WordPress plugin - WooCommerce.
I'm creating a script which would create a categories and subcategories, the problem is that I don't fully understand how all this works in WooCommerce DB structure.

That's what I was able to do:

In "wp_terms":

```
term_id | name              | slug     | term group
20      | Parent category   | parent   | 0
21      | Children category | children | 0
```

In "wp_term_taxonomy":

```
term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy    | description | parent | count
1                | 20      | product_cat |             | 0      | 0
2                | 21      | product_cat |             | 20     | 0
```

And that's working, but why the hell this don't:

In "wp_term_taxonomy":

```
term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy    | description | parent | count
1                | 20      | product_cat |             | 21     | 0
2                | 21      | product_cat |             | 0      | 0
```

Comment: What i understood is, You want to create category/subcategory from frontend or through script, Right?

Comment: I think it will help if you post your code that's not working here.

Answer (score 9):

```
function getParentCategories() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT term_id as id, name, slug FROM wp_terms where term_id in (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy where parent = 0 and taxonomy = 'category') order by name asc";
    $parents = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    return $parents;
}

function getChildCategories($id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT term_id as id, name, slug FROM wp_terms where term_id in (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy where parent = $id and taxonomy = 'category')  order by name asc";
    $children = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    return $children;
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the formatting of your code.

Comment: `getParentCategories()` retrieves all the parent categories.but,how to retrieve only the active parent category

Answer (score 2):

You have to look into table wp_options for option_name "product_cat_children", there is serialized category hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because one is the parent and the other the child, so if you define this relation, it's right that the opposite shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more step :  add your catoegory to the right products in : wp_term_relationships

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a problem: Subcategories were not displayed, despite the fact that both databases were filled correctly.
The following helped:

- Delete the value of the product_cat_children field in the wp_options table
- Update key values via admin panel in WooCommerce

This will update the value of the product_cat_children field.

Everything worked.