# Woocommerce - How do I determine which wp_term is a Product Category or not?

Tags: mysql, database, woocommerce

How do I determine which wp_term categories are woocommerce product categories or not?

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338454/how-do-categories-and-subcategories-for-woocommerce-are-saved-in-db ?

Comment: Check https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/9f98dcf9664c51e88900 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Kamil G.

You can find the categories by the wp_term_taxonomy

```
 wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

As is_product_category() can't be used to test other pages, a way to check if a WP_Term is a WooCommerce product category is:
`$term->taxonomy === "product_cat"`